# How do I use a variable in Postgres scripts?

Tags: postgresql, psql, variable-expansion

I'm working on a prototype that uses Postgres as its backend. I don't do a lot of SQL, so I'm feeling my way through it. I made a `.pgsql` file I run with `psql` that executes each of many files that set up my database, and I use a variable to define the schema that will be used so I can test features without mucking up my "good" instance:

```
\set schema_name 'example_schema'

\echo 'The Schema name is' :schema_name

\ir sql/file1.pgsql
\ir sql/file2.pgsql
```

This has been working well. I've defined several functions that expand `:schema_name` properly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION :schema_name.get_things_by_category(...
```

For reasons I can't figure out, this isn't working in my newest function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION :schema_name.update_thing_details(_id uuid, _details text)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
    UPDATE :schema_name.things
    ...
```

The syntax error indicates it's interpreting `:schema_name` literally after `UPDATE` instead of expanding it. How do I get it to use the variable value instead of the literal value here? I get that maybe within the `BEGIN..END` is a different context, but surely there's a way to script this schema name in all places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three approaches, since `psql` cannot do this directly.

**Shell script**

Use a bash script to perform the variable substitution and pipe the results into `psql`, like.

```
#!/bin/bash

$schemaName = $1
$contents = `cat script.sql | sed -e 's/@SCHEMA_NAME@/$schemaName'`

echo $contents | psql
```

This would probably be a lot of boiler plate if you have a lot of .sql scripts.

**Staging Schema**

Keep the approach you have now with a hard-coded schema of something like `staging` and then have a bash script go and rename `staging` to whatever you want the actual schema to be.

**Customize the search path**

Your entry point could be an inline script within bash that is piped into psql, does an up-front update of the default connection schema, then uses \ir to include all of your `.sql` files, which should *not* specify a schema.

```
#!/bin/bash

$schemaName = $1

psql <<SCRIPT
SET search_path TO $schemaName;
\ir sql/file1.pgsql
\ir sql/file2.pgsql
SCRIPT
```

Some details: [How to select a schema in postgres when using psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098326/how-to-select-a-schema-in-postgres-when-using-psql)

Personally I am leaning towards the latter approach as it seems the simplest and most scalable.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) says:

> Variable interpolation will not be performed within quoted SQL literals and identifiers. Therefore, a construction such as `':foo'` doesn't work to produce a quoted literal from a variable's value (and it would be unsafe if it did work, since it wouldn't correctly handle quotes embedded in the value).

Now the function body is a “dollar-quoted%rdquo; string literal (`$BODY$...$BODY$`), so the variable will not be replaced there.

I can't think of a way to do this with `psql` variables.