# Django error on connecting to Postgres, unsupported startup parameter: options

Tags: django, postgresql

On migrate step I get such error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: ERROR:  unsupported startup parameter: options`

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=public'
        },
        'NAME': env.str('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': env.str('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env.str('DB_PASS'),
        'HOST': env.str('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': env.str('DB_PORT'),
        'DISABLE_SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS': True,
    }
}
```

(in options parameter I tried to set default schema to `public`)

Can this error appear because I have `pgbouncer`?

Comment: No because you are using  `options` which is not recognized by the driver e.g. `psycopg2`. You are trying to use a command line option in a non command line situation. Don't know if it will work but you might try `'OPTIONS': {'search_path': 'public'}`

Comment: Same problem. Think its becuse of pgbouncer. Try to set pgbouncer param ignore_startup_parameters to  "options"  https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/10/pgbouncer